# How to predict seasonal spikes in time series and ignore spikes which are not seasonal?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I have just started with time series forecasting and trying to figure out the solution for following use case.
I want to detect non-seasonal alerts coming into our system. If incoming alerts are seasonal I want to ignore them. Outliers which do not fit into a seasonal pattern I need to escalate them to the processing module.

```
#Creating time series which has spikes every 20th time interval.
alert_once_a_day = [1.0 if i % 20 == 0 else 0.0  for i in range(100)]
#Adding an outlier at 27, which does not fit pattern of spikes at every 20 th interval.
alert_once_a_day[27] =1.0
```

In the above series, I want to find all alerts occur in seasonal pattern and ignore them.

Comment: Do you mean, "I want to detect **non**-seasonal alerts"? I.e., ignore seasonal spikes, look for outlying spikes?

Comment: Are your alerts binary 0/1?

Comment: Also, can the `alert_once_a_day` array just be made as a boolean array? Or is it expect to be an array of decimal values? E.g., is `0.5` a possible value?

Comment: It will be a boolean array. There will not be any other values expect 0 and 1.

Comment: Do you know the time between seasons or can the difference be any number?

Comment: It can be any number. Can I use something like scipy.signal.welch to find periodogram?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer, use a mask:

```
alert_once_a_day = [1.0 if i % 20 == 0 else 0.0  for i in range(100)]

seasonal_alerts = list(alert_once_a_day)
mask = np.array(seasonal_alerts) == 0

#Adding an outlier at 27, which does not fit pattern of spikes at every 20 th interval.
alert_once_a_day[27] =1.0

# assuming your zeros are "non alert" values, the mask will eliminate seasonal peaks:    
true_alerts = np.where(np.array(alert_once_a_day) * mask==1)
true_alerts
>> (array([27], dtype=int64),)
```